# Div under another div that fills the space in the parent

Tags: css, materialize

Putting it simple.

Here is what I done:

https://codepen.io/matt1991/pen/abdeZNv

I've tried using flexbox to a extent, tried to mess with a lot of classes and properties, and yet can't do what I need, that is:

I need the div `right-down` to fill the space under the div `right-up` until both of them, together, have the same height of `left`, using only css, on a system built up on materialize.css. I know how to do that with javascript involved, but I want to make it using only css, in a way that, if `left` or `right-up` get more or less text, the size stays the same.

ps.: The red div MUST stop at the green one, it cannot go until the top and z-indexed behind the green one.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to add height:100vh; in your right area

Comment: @SaifWarsi did not work, it got a 'static' height, similar on how it would be if i had set it in pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's okay to remove the materialize.css it's easy:

```
<div id="main" class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div id="left">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a aliquam urna, non imperdiet turpis. Nullam id mauris vel neque eleifend sollicitudin sit amet nec justo. Mauris auctor, erat nec bibendum posuere, nibh justo elementum orci, ut convallis tellus risus a orci. Integer sodales viverra erat, quis tincidunt ante ornare sit amet. Donec sed urna urna. Cras in lectus in erat iaculis euismod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam rutrum in lorem eget tristique. Nam at ex commodo, vestibulum nulla quis, convallis dolor. Etiam posuere augue massa. In pulvinar vitae dolor vel feugiat.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a aliquam urna, non imperdiet turpis. Nullam id mauris vel neque eleifend sollicitudin sit amet nec justo. Mauris auctor, erat nec bibendum posuere, nibh justo elementum orci, ut convallis tellus risus a orci. Integer sodales viverra erat, quis tincidunt ante ornare sit amet. Donec sed urna urna. Cras in lectus in erat iaculis euismod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam rutrum in lorem eget tristique. Nam at ex commodo, vestibulum nulla quis, convallis dolor. Etiam posuere augue massa. In pulvinar vitae dolor vel feugiat.
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div id="right-up">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a aliquam urna, non imperdiet turpis. Nullam id mauris vel neque eleifend sollicitudin sit amet nec justo. Mauris auctor, erat nec bibendum posuere, nibh justo elementum orci, ut convallis tellus risus a orci. 
      </div>
      <div id="right-down"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  height: 100%
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 2;
}


#right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

#right-up {
  background-color: green;
}

#right-down {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: I can't remove the materialize, the whole system is built up on top of it.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should remove the whole system, just the css classes for this small piece here, then my solution above works.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, now i'm gonna read everything and try to understand.

Comment: I made another example were all the css classes are in use: https://codepen.io/JohMun/pen/PoZMGgq

But I added some rules to .col and .row to make it work. I think my first solution is the better one.

Comment: How you made it so the left column have 66% of the container (col s8) and the other two 33%? can't find anything on the css or the classes

Comment: found out. Thanks again.

Comment: In the first example it is done with `#left { flex: 2; }` and `#right { flex: 1; }`.